# how to use this keyword in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to typescript and please help me how to get loginservice inside authenticate function. I have used this keyword to get loginservice but it is not working. And also I'm confused with this keyword in typescript.

```
import { Constants } from '../../core/constants';
    import { loginService } from './login.service';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })

    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private loginservice: loginService) { }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

      login = {

        formData: {
          username: '',
          password: '',
        },

        resources:{
          login_logo: Constants.LOGO_LOGIN,
        },

        authenticate() {
          console.log("service called");
          let resultset = loginservice.authenticateUser(this.formData);

        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is actually two questions, and the latter is too broad to be answered in this format. Having said that, it may be helpful for you to know that `loginservice` is already set to `this` because you have used the `private` keyword inside the constructor call.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much difference.

```
let resultset = loginservice...
```

should be

```
let resultset = this.loginservice.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you use the `this.` keyword to refer to attributes on the class. The parameters in the constructor also become attributes on the class automatically. So like the previous answer says, you just do `this.loginservice`

Comment: Note the parameters of the constructor only become attributes automatically because OP uses the `private` keyword. Without `private`, each argument would have to be set to `this` inside the constructor call.

Comment: I didn't know either until I forgot to add `private` and I couldn't figure out why nothing would work.

Answer (score 1):

**Your code has a couple of fundamental issues. Try this updated code:**

```
import { Constants } from '../../core/constants';
import { loginService } from './login.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private loginservice: loginService, private CONSTANTS : Constants) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  formData: any ={
     username: '',
     password: '',
  };

  resources: any = {
      login_logo: this.CONSTANTS.LOGO_LOGIN,
  };


  authenticate() {
      console.log("service called");
      let resultset = this.loginservice.authenticateUser(this.formData);

  }
}
```

Comment: Is it wrong to group everything to a single object(login)? Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes , you can't group like this especially you can't do methods like this

Answer (score 0):

Actually this refers to the current context , in your code, you have imported login service inside constructor so it should be consumed as,

```
authenticate() {
   console.log("service called");
  let resultset = this.loginservice.authenticateUser(this.formData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below scenario, the `this` keyword refers to the attributes within the LoginComponent (TypeScript file), such as the loginService, for example.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  ... 

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  ...

  public authenticate(): void {
    let resultset = this.loginService.authenticateUser(this.formData);
    ...
  }
}
```